# How to Create folder with VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I need to know how i can check if the folder exist, and if it does not exist, create it

For Example:

```
If File.Exists(File Path) Then

   Else
       'Create a new folder following the path(Path here)
End If
```

And Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using this class in order to determine if the folder exists: [.Net Directory Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as well as [.Net File Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to find the functionality you need. Both of them offers an "Exists" function and a "Create" function.

If you have the case where multiple folders in the path don't exist (which you might want to consider checking for), you would need to include a loop to iterative create every folder in the path until you've reached your destination.

Comment: Since you're duplicating an answer, why not [include relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/86016/1454048) as well?

Comment: Didn't realize this was a duplicate answer. I answered ~1 hr before it was marked a duplicate, and I honestly didn't bother to search for it before I answered. My apologies.